# Hypertrack- Angular css override issue

Tags: css, angular, hypertrack

I am integrating Hypertrack in my angular 5 app as per

https://github.com/hypertrack/angular-dashboard-demo

As hypertrack css is external i have to include it in style URL or angular-cli.json style

**.angular-cli.json**

```
"styles": [
         "../node_modules/ht-angular/src/styles/bulma.scss",
         "../node_modules/ht-angular/src/styles/global.scss",
         "../node_modules/ht-angular/src/styles/placeholder.scss",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

I have left styles.css i case of any overrrides.

**If i include these css here my project css gets affected.**

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
 styleUrls: [
    '../../../../node_modules/ht-angular/src/styles/bulma.scss',
    '../../../../node_modules/ht-angular/src/styles/global.scss',
    '../../../../node_modules/ht-angular/src/styles/placeholder.scss',
    './dashboard.component.css',
]
})
```

If i include css here there is no change.

How can i import external css without changes in my project?

Edit 1:
I have created a git repo other than my project.
https://github.com/rgnrw/hypertrack_css_issue.git

Now i am unable to add bootstrap into this

Comment: Can you please share a repo. Not able to understand the issue you are facing. Are the styles in dashboard component.css not being applied?

Comment: my project css changes if i import css in angular cli

Comment: repo link..
https://github.com/rgnrw/hypertrack_css_issue.git